# Chamar método com parâmetro de outro método em Java?

Tags: java

Teria como eu chamar um método com parâmetro sendo um objeto de uma outra classe, mas esse objeto é criado em um método anterior?

Exemplo:

ClasseA:

```
Public void cadastrar (Cliente cliente){
      System.out.println (cliente.getNome());

}
```

ClasseB:

```
Public void metodoDois (){

 Cliente cliente = new Cliente();

}

ClasseA chamada = new classeA();
    Chamada.cadastrar(cliente);
```

Comment: O método `metodoDois` do jeito que está escrito é amplamente inútil, exceto por um eventual efeito colateral não claro que possa surgir ao instanciar `cliente`. Variável locais (e argumentos também) só podem ser usados dentro do escopo da função. Seu exemplo não fica claro o que deseja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da forma que está não é possível

Você pode alterar o `metodoDois()` e passar ele por parâmetro para o método `cadastrar()`:

ClasseA:

```
Public void cadastrar (Cliente cliente){
    System.out.println (cliente.getNome());
}
```

ClasseB:

```
Public Cliente metodoDois() {
    return new Cliente();
}

ClasseA chamada = new classeA();
Chamada.cadastrar(metodoDois());
```

Ou criar uma variável fora da função `metodoDois()` que vai ser modificada na chamada da função e então passar como parâmetro do `cadastrar()`:

ClasseA:

```
Public void cadastrar (Cliente cliente){
    System.out.println (cliente.getNome());
}
```

ClasseB:

```
Cliente cliente;

Public void metodoDois() {
    this.cliente = new Cliente();
}

ClasseA chamada = new classeA();
metodoDois();
Chamada.cadastrar(cliente);
```